# Automatically Transfering Files from Gmail to a Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, gmail

Is it possible to hook up a Gmail account to a server and create a script so that file attachments whose names fit a certain format will automatically be transferred to the server and stored in a newly created folder?  Does this sound needlessly complex?

Comment: Check [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), it may be helpful here.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks, that does seem interesting but I'm a bit skeptical of the legitimacy of the recipes given how little information the site provides.